Which members of the Straw Hat Pirates can survive by their own deep underwater?
I'm watching One Piece: Gyojin Tou-hen . In episode five, Nami says Luffy and the others are going to want to fight, but they can't because they 10,000 meters underwater. But in episode 3-4, Luffy, Zoro and Sanji fought several thousand meters underwater, and two of their air bubbles broke, so they survived several thousand meters underwater
Which members of the Straw Hat Pirates can survive by their own deep underwater?

What do you mean by "survive"? Obviously all the Strawhats at that point, possibly with the exception of Brook, will drown in a couple of minutes. Are you interested in pressure specifically (I don't remember if it's something that is ever mentioned in OP, but it doesn't look like something that is being takent into account)?

If I remember right Nami was referring to them being overly zealous. Initially they didn't know that the bubbles were going to work like they did, and even when they were fighting from with-in them they could have popped. Because they were in the bubble coated sunny, they had the opportunity to fight in the bubbles. Normally though Jinbae (and this isn't until the end of big-mom arc) would be the only strawhat that could fight underwater like that. And FYI brook might not survive because he is a power holder, so even  though he can walk on sea water, he can't go into it.

@AKUMAnoONI The problem with Brook and water is that being submerged in water is not poisonous for DF users: it just weakens them enormously. In some cases it doesn't even deactivate their DF. The reason they die is that they can't stay afloat and need to breathe. Now, Brook does not operate on lungs: he's just kept alive by the fact that his DF granted him a "super soul" that can operate his body out of sheer will. So the questions are: 1) does he need to breathe? 2) if not, does his DF deactivate underwater? (continues...)

@AKUMAnoONI (continuation...) The answer to (2) seems to be "No", because, while he is kept alive by his "super soul", the reason he is alive in the first place is that his DF granted him a "second chance at life", meaning that he could return to his body after death only that one time. So if water could immediately shut down his life support, then he would die as soon as he is submerged (and that seems like something that has happened at some point).
